# Nested looping over tuple values in a dictionary with tuple keys python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict where the key is a 4-tuple (gene_region, species, ontology, length).

Looping over it is simple:

```
for gene_region, species, ontology, length in result_dict:
```

However, I'd like to iterate over it in a nested fashion, like this:

```
for gene_region
    for species
        for ontology
            ...
```

How do I do this? Is there no other way than collecting the values first? Or using the following dum-dum way:

```
for gene_region, _, _, _ in result_dict:
    for _, species, _, _ in result_dict:
        ...
```

Comment: What do you expect to *do* with the loops? Create a product of the 4 values? What are the `gen_region`, etc. values, exactly? Lists, strings, integers?

Comment: The keys are all strings, the values in the dict are just numbers I want to compare.

Comment: But you have tuples as keys, what do you expect the loops to loop over. All possible values for `gen_region`? You cannot do that without listing all the keys first, collecting the individual elements of the tuples into separate structures, then looping over those. Then you'd need to reconstruct keys from that..

Comment: Write that up as an answer and I'll accept it (if no one else has any cleverer ideas.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to collect all the various key elements into lists, then loop over those (using [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), preferably). The collecting can be done with `zip()`:

```
from itertools import product

gene_regions, species_plural, ontologies, lengths = zip(*result_dict)

for gene_region, species, ontology, length in product(gene_regions, species_plural, ontologies, lengths):
    # do something with this combo.
```

`product()` produces the same sequence of combinations as if you had nested your loops.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could consider recreating your data as nested dictionaries:

```
>>> result_dict = {}
>>> result_dict[(1, 2, 3, 4)] = "test"
>>> result_dict[(1, 2, 4, 4)] = "test2"
>>> result_dict
{(1, 2, 3, 4): 'test', (1, 2, 4, 4): 'test2'}

>>> result_dict2 = {}
>>> for (a, b, c, d), k in result_dict.iteritems():
...     result_dict2.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, {}).setdefault(c, {})[d] = k
... 
>>> result_dict2
{1: {2: {3: {4: 'test'}, 4: {4: 'test2'}}}}
```

then you can iterate over the keys on any level:

```
for _, a in result_dict2.iteritems():
    for _, b in a.iteritems():
        for _, c in b.iteritems():
            for _, d in c.iteritems():
                # do something
```

Comment: You could make your looping a bit more robust by using `reduce` here: eg.... `for k, v in result_dict.iteritems(): reduce(lambda a, b: a.setdefault(b, {}), k[:-1], result_dict2)[k[-1]] = v`

Comment: nice :) I didn't actually liked this long chain of setdefault, but didn't think about reducing them this way